# Getting "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No ClassLoaders found for:" exception when receiving serialization object

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am trying to access set of Java class files from my web page. Serialized object is passed to the web application and  the following error has thrown when receiving the serialized object in the web app.Previously i used java 1.5.At that time it was working fine. Now i moved to java 1.7.Now getting this exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No ClassLoaders found for : classfile name.
```

All the class files are present in the **/WEB_INF/classes** directory. How do I solve this?

Comment: and the servlet.jar is in tomcat/lib?

Comment: Full stack trace? If it occurs in your code, could you also include the relevant part?

Comment: @santro Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got the solution for the issue.modifying the parameter "UseJBossWebLoader" as true in the jboss configuration file. –

Comment: Which Jboss did you use?

Comment: I think I've similar problem but I was uprading messaging in jboss 4.2.2 GA and setting this parameter doesn't work for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238493/org-jboss-mx-loading-loadmgr3-beginloadtask-after-invoke-clustered-jms-apps